# Is there a function in perl to check if 2 arrays contain the same contents(although NOT necessarily the same order)?

Tags: arrays, perl

I know you could go one element at a time, but that would be really inefficient. Is there a better way?.
e.g

```
my @end_list =qw(
VDD1_DDR1_S2[2:1]
VDD2_DDR3_S2[5:1]
VDD1_DDR3_S2[2:1]
VDD2_DDR1_S2[5:1]
VDD2_DDR2_S2[5:1]
VDD1_DDR2_S2[2:1]
VDD1_DDR0_S2[2:1]
VDD2_DDR0_S2[5:1]
);
```

and

```
my @expected_list =qw(
                      VDD1_DDR0_S2_[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR0_S2_[5:1]
                      VDD1_DDR1_S2_[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR1_S2_[5:1]
                      VDD1_DDR2_S2_[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR2_S2_[5:1]
                      VDD1_DDR3_S2_[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR3_S2_[5:1]
      );
```

would be the same in spite of the contents being in a different order.

Comment: I actually intended for endlist to have `_` to the left of `[` in endlist as well.

Comment: I do like the answer though! just what I was looking for

Comment: are `"a","b","c"` and `"a","b","c","c"` considered the same or different?

Answer (score 5):

Since we're talking about strings,

```
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @m;
--$counts{$_} for @n;
die "Different" if grep $_, values(%counts);
```

While not relevant here, you can even use this function with things other than strings by using a key function that returns the same string for values you consider identical and different strings for value you consider different.

For example, if you wanted to support `undef` as well as strings, and if you wanted the comparisons to be case-insensitive, you could use the following:

```
sub key { defined($_[0]) ? '1'.fc($_[0]) : '0' }

my %counts;
++$counts{key($_)} for @m;
--$counts{key($_)} for @n;
die "Different" if grep $_, values(%counts);
```

Either way, O(M + N) speed and memory.

Comment: warnings on undefined values :)

Comment: @k-mx, I specifically said it'll work for *strings*. But I've added an explanation as to how you can extend it to work with other values.

Answer (score 4):

Using `perm` from [Array::Compare](https://metacpan.org/pod/Array::Compare) on CPAN ignores order:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Array::Compare qw();

my @end_list =qw(
VDD1_DDR1_S2[2:1]
VDD2_DDR3_S2[5:1]
VDD1_DDR3_S2[2:1]
VDD2_DDR1_S2[5:1]
VDD2_DDR2_S2[5:1]
VDD1_DDR2_S2[2:1]
VDD1_DDR0_S2[2:1]
VDD2_DDR0_S2[5:1]
);

my @expected_list =qw(
                      VDD1_DDR0_S2[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR0_S2[5:1]
                      VDD1_DDR1_S2[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR1_S2[5:1]
                      VDD1_DDR2_S2[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR2_S2[5:1]
                      VDD1_DDR3_S2[2:1]
                      VDD2_DDR3_S2[5:1]
      );

my $comp = Array::Compare->new();

if ($comp->perm(\@end_list, \@expected_list)) {
    print "Arrays are perms\n";
}
else {
    print "Nope. Arrays are completely different\n";
}
```

**Note**: I removed the `_` before the `[` in each item in `@expected_list`.

This outputs:

```
Arrays are perms
```